# In c# tree view, checkbox and Imagelist icon overlapping, How to fix this?

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview, icons, nodes

I am working on developing tree view in C# wherein directories and files are to be loaded. `TreeView` and directories are successfully loaded. I need to have checkboxes with every tree node and also I want to have corresponding icons (eg. for directory - a folder icon, and for files - a file icon). When I try to do that, checkboxes and icons overlaps. Following is some snap shots for that -

[image: Please click to see image]

Following is the Image List code in `Form1.Designer.cs` file:

```cs
this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "Folder_256x256.png");
this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(1, "document-management-big.png");
```

Following is the Directory and files loading code in `Form1.cs` file:

```cs
public void LoadDirectory(string Dir)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Dir);
    //MessageBox.Show(di.Name.ToString());
    //Setting ProgressBar Maximum Value
    progressBar1.Maximum = Directory.GetFiles(Dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length + Directory.GetDirectories(Dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    TreeNode tds = treeView1.Nodes.Add(di.Name);
    tds.Tag = di.FullName;
    tds.StateImageIndex = 0; //Code for loading/linking with icon
    LoadFiles(Dir, tds);
    LoadSubDirectories(Dir, tds);
}

private void LoadSubDirectories(string dir, TreeNode td)
{
    // Get all subdirectories
    string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
    // Loop through them to see if they have any other subdirectories
    foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
    {

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(subdirectory);
        TreeNode tds = td.Nodes.Add(di.Name);
        tds.StateImageIndex = 0; //Code for loading/linking with icon
        tds.Tag = di.FullName;
        LoadFiles(subdirectory, tds);
        LoadSubDirectories(subdirectory, tds);
        UpdateProgress();

    }
}

private void LoadFiles(string dir, TreeNode td)
{
    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*");

    // Loop through them to see files
    foreach (string file in Files)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        TreeNode tds = td.Nodes.Add(fi.Name);
        tds.Tag = fi.FullName;
        tds.StateImageIndex = 1; //Code for loading/linking with icon
        UpdateProgress();
    }
}
```

The `CheckBox` is directly enabled in the `TreeView` by writing code in `Form1.Designer.cs` file :

```cs
this.treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```

The problem is already explained - icons and checkboxes are overlapping. Please help me in this. Not getting any solution on internet as per my research.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see any checkbox on your snapshot - but maybe that's what you meant by "overlapping"?

Comment: When you create a new _TreeNode_, set both _ImageIndex_ and _SelectedImageIndex_ properties to display the images. Also, make sure you assign the _ImageList_ component to the _ImageList_ property of the _TreeView_ control.

Comment: @CorentinPane Exactly!

Comment: @JQSOFT Setting ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex property as per the indexes didn't worked. But what you are trying to explain in second sentence? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: You need to assign the `ImageList1` component to the `TreeView.ImageList` property in order to make use for the `ImageIndex`, `ImageKey`, `SelectedImageIndex` and `SelectedImageKey` properties.

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks a lot!! It really worked for me. Anyone need to know in depth execution for the same problem, go to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-icons-for-the-windows-forms-treeview-control